# Websphere 7.0 Work Manager Max Threads Ignored?

Tags: application-server, websphere, java, pool

I'm trying to chase down a bug in an internal application and as part of this work I noticed an apparent discrepancy between the "Maximum number of threads" setting in WAS (BASE 7.0.0.0 r0835.03) and a thread dump that I took while the server was running. I'd like to know if this behavior is correct or if it's potentially a bug, either in WAS or our application.

So, in WAS I have a Work Manager configured at server scope:
MyWorkManager
Work Timeout: 0
Work Request Queue Size: 0
Queue Full: Block
Service Names: Security (only)
Alarm Threads: 2
Min Threads: 0
Max Threads: 5
Thread Priority: 5
NOT GROWABLE

Once our application is up and using the work manager, I take a thread dump using wsadmin and there are **19 threads** actively doing work that have the name:

java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=MyWorkManager: my_ear,maxpri=10]

I would have assumed that we'd see a maximum of 5 work manager threads. Any ideas as to what could be going on or further diagnostics that I can run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by applying WAS 7 [fixpack 15](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg24020446). Apparently this was a bug in Websphere.